# Covert from Nornir 2.3.0 to Nornir 3.2.0

Tags: python, automation, network-programming

Need to get username and password from shell input

```
def adapt_host_data(host):
    host.username = Gusername
    host.password = Gpassword

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Gusername = input('Username: ')
    Gpassword = getpass('Password: ')

    nr = InitNornir(
    inventory={
                "plugin": "nornir.plugins.inventory.simple.SimpleInventory",
                "options": {
                    "host_file": "./inventory/hostise.yaml",
                    "group_file": "./inventory/groups.yaml"
                            },
                "transform_function": adapt_host_data,
            },)
```

This is working fine under Nornir 2.3.0. But iam not able to use this under Nornir 3.2.0.
Please help

This is the error i get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filesname.py", line 70, in <module>
    "transform_function": adapt_host_data,
  File "/heim/tahir/scripts/Python/nornir/envNornir3/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/nornir/init_nornir.py", line 72, in InitNornir
    inventory=load_inventory(config),
  File "/heim/tahir/scripts/Python/nornir/envNornir3/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/nornir/init_nornir.py", line 19, in load_inventory
    inventory_plugin = InventoryPluginRegister.get_plugin(config.inventory.plugin)
  File "/heim/tahir/scripts/Python/nornir/envNornir3/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/nornir/core/plugins/register.py", line 76, in get_plugin
    raise PluginNotRegistered(f"plugin {name!r} is not registered")
nornir.core.exceptions.PluginNotRegistered: plugin 'nornir.plugins.inventory.simple.SimpleInventory' is not registered
```

Comment: Please add the error message that you are being thrown to the question as this would be the clue into how to help answer it.

Comment: I have added the error in my quesion now

Answer (score 0):

Needed to register InventoryPluginRegister and SimpleInventory

```
def transform_func(host):
    host.username = Gusername
    host.password = Gpassword

if __name__ == "__main__":

    from nornir.core.plugins.inventory import InventoryPluginRegister
    from nornir.plugins.inventory import SimpleInventory
    from nornir.core.plugins.inventory import TransformFunctionRegister
    InventoryPluginRegister.register("SimpleInventory", SimpleInventory)
    TransformFunctionRegister.register("transform_func", transform_func)

    Gusername = input('Username: ')
    Gpassword = getpass('Password: ')
#
    nr = InitNornir(config_file="./inventory/config.yaml")
```

And the config.yaml have to look like this

```
inventory:
  plugin: SimpleInventory
  transform_function: transform_func
  options:
    host_file: "./inventory/hostise.yaml"
    group_file: "./inventory/groups.yaml"
    defaults_file: "./inventory/defaults.yaml"

logging:
  enabled: False
```